# removeFromSuperview doesn't work for UIView's added to SKScene

Tags: uiview, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am adding a UIView to the view of an SKScene.  Later, when I wish to remove that UIView form its superview, using the standard method of uiview.removeFromSuperview does not seem to work. How should I be accomplishing this instead?  Here is how I add the UIView:

```
func addContainerView() {

    let containerRect = CGRectMake(400, 24, 600, 720)
    smallerView = UIView(frame: containerRect)
    smallerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(smallerView)
}
```

Here is how I am attempting to remove it:

```
func removeContainerView() {

    smallerView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

This all takes place within the SKScene class, so here 'self' refers to that scene.
Any thoughts?

Comment: You actually add it to `self.view`, which is `SKView`

Comment: Thanks @AndreyGordeev, this is an interesting observation, an quite true, but I am not sure how it affects my problem.  SKView inherits from UIView, and so removing subviews should work in the same manner, right?

Comment: This works fine for me. There must be something else that is causing it to stay on screen. I added a view during viewDidLoad in the SceneKit template and remove it in the handleTap method and everything works as expected.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005261/removefromsuperview-doesnt-work

Needs to be removed on main thread.

Comment: No, this is still an issue which I have not figured out the solution to, and the issue you linked to doesn't help me.  Removing the UIView from the SKScene on the Main Thread does not help.  Please do not remove this.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked that removeContainerView() is actually called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I wonder which version of swift your are using.

`self.view` is *optional* in 1.2
hence your should type: `self.view?.addSubview()` if you are targeting swift 1.2

I have tried in swift 1.2 to make a simple app

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

  let subview = UIView()

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    subview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    subview.backgroundColor = SKColor.orangeColor()
    self.view?.addSubview(subview)
  }

  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    removeContainerView()
  }

  func removeContainerView() {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
  }
}
```

The above code works very well.
I can think of a couple of reasons your view doesn't get removed

1. Are you sure that `removeContainerView` is actually called. Try to make a break point to see if it's called
2. If you have set up your SKView in code something might have been setup wrong.
3. Your subview is being deallocated or something

To fully debug your problem we need to see some more code.

What we need is:

1. Declaration of your subview
2. All functions that call removeContainerView()

Even better would be to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) your SKScene class.